# Debug C++ Standard Library with Visual Studio Code on macOS

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks

I am using *Visual Studio Code* on macOS with the *Microsoft C/C++ Extension* to evaluate the real usability and productivity in a production environment.

In my scenario, I am using *Clang/LLVM* compiler and *LLDB* debugger.

For some unknown reason, I am unable to debug the C++ Standard Library. I can step into symbols defined in my application, but no way do the same with the standard ones, e.g. `std::vector` constructor.

It is unclear whether this is an incorrect configuration or a limitation of these tools. Searching on web I noticed that the C++ standard library debugging definitely works well on Linux using the GNU toolchain.

Is there a way to debug standard symbols using *LLDB* debugger? Does anyone use these tools in production?

For completeness, it follows my current and quite simple configuration:

`tasks.json`:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-std=c++17",
                "-stdlib=libc++",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/clang++"
        }
    ]
}
```

`launch.json`:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(lldb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "console": "externalTerminal",
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "${defaultBuildTask}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Microsoft C/C++ Extension support team points out that this is due to the default configuration of `lldb`. In fact, `target.process.thread.step-avoid-regexp` is set to `^std::` by default:

```
(lldb) settings show target.process.thread.step-avoid-regexp
target.process.thread.step-avoid-regexp (regex) = ^std::
```

Changing this setting to `""`, the debugger is able to step into standard template symbols as well. This can be configured in the `launch.json` configuration file by adding:

```json
"setupCommands": [
    {
        "text": "settings set target.process.thread.step-avoid-regexp \"\"",
        "description": "Enable stepping into STL"
    }
]
```

Alternatively, this can also be set at the user level by placing this configuration in the `.gdbinit` file in the home directory:

```
settings set target.process.thread.step-avoid-regexp ""
```